# How to error check for spaces and decimals when entering multiple integers in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter the amount of items they want to order for a series of items, and then store that input individually into a series of int variables. I've defined my variables and then prompted the user for the number of orders for each item and then stored that input into variables as so:

```
int apples, bananas, pears, grapes;

cout << "Enter number of apples to order: " ;
cin >> apples;

cout << "Enter number of bananas to order: " ;
cin >> bananas;

cout << "Enter number of pears to order: " ;
cin >> pears;

cout << "Enter number of grapes to order: " ;
cin >> grapes;

cout << apples << endl << bananas << endl << pears << endl << grapes;
```

This all works as intended, however the issue comes up when I execute the program and type in an input with whitespace or a decimal input. For example if I tried entering "4 9 6 7" or "5.46", then the program would skip a over prompting the user for the rest of the items.

I understand that the reason this is happening is because the input buffer doesn't clear after each input and will continue from it left off (at least in the case of whitespace), but what I'm trying to figure out is how to automatically error check for this. What I would ideally want to happen is in the case of whitespace being entered the program would take the first integer and clear the input buffer so that the remaining items can be ordered, and in the case of a decimal the program would simply truncate the decimal portion and take the whole number.

I have tried using cin.get() and cin.getline() to try and clear the input buffer, but they don't make a difference in the output. I have also tried using cin.clear() and cin.ignore() but they don't work either. I don't want to use a looping mechanism because I haven't gotten to those yet and would like to understand how to do it with more simpler commands.

Thank you.

Edit: I guess what I'm asking is how can I simply clear out the input buffer after each input statement? I'm essentially looking for something similar to adding the "nextLine()" statement in Java after an input statement.

Comment: *I don't want to use a looping mechanism because I haven't gotten to those yet and would like to understand how to do it with more simpler commands.* -- I doubt there is any magic C++ function that does what you want.  The way it's usually done is to read the data in as a string, see if the string is a valid integer, and if not, fix the data yourself and go on.

Comment: But isn't there a way to simply clear out the input buffer after each input statement so that the next input statement will run as normal? Because I know that in Java if I come across this problem I can just write "nextLine()" to fix this, so what I guess I'm asking is how could I do this in C++?

Comment: *Because I know that in Java...* -- Say this a hundred times -- *C++ is not Java*.

Comment: Does `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` clears the rest of the line if that's what you need.

Comment: @FeiXiang You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the input a whole line at a time and then scan that whole line like this:

```
std::string line;

std::cout << "Enter number of apples to order: " ;
std::getline(std::cin, line); // get a whole line

// now re-input that line by converting it into
// an input stream
std::istringstream iss(line);

iss >> apples; // do error checking here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you get the inputs and parse them in one line.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int apples, bananas, pears, grapes;
    cout << "Enter no of apples, bananas, pears, grapes:" << endl;
    cin >> apples >> bananas >> pears >> grapes;
    cout << "apples: " << apples << "; bananas: " << bananas << "; pears: " << pears << "; grapes: " << grapes << endl;
}
```

This will run like the following:

Enter no of apples, bananas, pears, grapes:
1 2 3 4
apples: 1; bananas: 2; pears: 3; grapes: 4

Answer (score -1):

Input sanitation can be pretty difficult.  As a simple way of handling this you could try capturing the input as a string and then parse the string to ensure it is correct.

Minimal example:

```
int ParseInput(const std::string& input)
{
    int result = 0;

    if ( input.empty( ) )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < input.size( ); i++)
    {
        if ( !isdigit(input[i]) )
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return atoi(input.c_str( ));
}

int main( )
{
    std::string line;
    int apples, bananas, pears, grapes;

    cout << "Enter number of apples to order: " ;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    apples = ParseInput(line);
    //.
    //.
    //.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would fail many inputs I would consider valid. Leading or trailing whitespace, negative numbers, for instance

Comment: That's what makes the example "minimal"; this isn't meant as a general solution to all problems of this class.  Given the example program stated in the problem, ordering a negative number of fruits doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Use **array of char** or **string** to buffer data.

Try this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*limit the buffer size*/
#define MAX_BUFFER 20

int main()
{
    char apples[MAX_BUFFER], bananas[MAX_BUFFER], pears[MAX_BUFFER], grapes[MAX_BUFFER];
    std::fill_n(apples, MAX_BUFFER, 0);
    std::fill_n(bananas, MAX_BUFFER, 0);
    std::fill_n(pears, MAX_BUFFER, 0);
    std::fill_n(grapes, MAX_BUFFER, 0);

    cout << "Enter number of apples to order: " ;
    cin.getline(apples,MAX_BUFFER);

    cout << "Enter number of bananas to order: " ;
    cin.getline(bananas,MAX_BUFFER);

    cout << "Enter number of pears to order: " ;
    cin.getline(pears,MAX_BUFFER);

    cout << "Enter number of grapes to order: " ;
    cin.getline(grapes,MAX_BUFFER);

    cout << apples << endl << bananas << endl << pears << endl << grapes;
    return 0;
}
```

with this, you can now manipulate every character of apples, bananas, pears, grapes.

Comment: Why fixed size char arrays instead of strings? Also doesn't really answer the question because the OP wants integers.

Comment: for less memory and overhead. Well, this is a good practice of coding. you can google it anyway.

Comment: @John he doesn't want integer but wanted a way to make checking of the input possible.